# How to get ip address on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Now I have a requirement to get IP address on iPhone.

Only cellular, how to get IP address?

Only WIFI, how to get IP address?

Both WIFI and cellular, how to get the IP address which is being used?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need the external IP address:

Use a UIWebView and then call this API and parse it's JSON:

http://ip-api.com/json